# How many planar graphs of vertex degrees all $\ge4$ are there?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

How many **planar** graphs that satisfies $\forall\ v\in V\deg(v)\ge4$ are there?

If there are finite numbers, can you list them/link them?

If there are infinite, is there a proof?

I assume there are infinite, as if there are only a finite number, the Four Color Theorem (which led to this question) would be trivial.

Comment: It's really not good to change a question once you've received an answer. Better to ask a new question (and link each to the other).

Comment: For another infinite family, note that the edges of an octahedron form a planar graph with all vertices of degree four, and just join as many octahedra as you like together to get more examples.

Comment: OK, I will do that, G.M.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there are infinitely many of them.

Here's an example: a graph made of vertices arranged in a $5 \times 5$ square grid, and for each side of the grid, there is an extra vertex that is adjacent to all 'outer' vertices of that side.

[image: An example of a planar graph with minimum degree 4]

It's quite obvious that the planar graph above satisfies the minimum degree $4$ requirement. In fact, as long as the grid is $4 \times 4$ or larger, the requirement will be satisfied. Hence, there's an infinite number of such graphs.