# How many planar graphs of vertex degrees all ≥4 are there?, extended (by request of G.M.)

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

An extension to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4502808/1064880).

How many planar graphs of vertex degrees all ≥4 are there?

Now that I have seen infinite cases (from [VTand's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4502822/1064880)), is there any way to describe **all** of them? i.e. Does all planar graphs that conform to the above limitations follow one of several patterns?

1. Yes, and we have found all the patterns.
2. No, and we have a proof.
3. It is not solved (or recognized) yet.

VTand's answer:

> Yes, there are infinitely many of them.
>
> Here's an example: a graph made of vertices arranged in a $5 \times 5$ square grid, and for each side of the grid, there is an extra vertex that is adjacent to all 'outer' vertices of that side.
>
> [image: An example of a planar graph with minimum degree 4]
>
> It's quite obvious that the planar graph above satisfies the minimum degree $4$ requirement. In fact, as long as the grid is $4 \times 4$ or larger, the requirement will be satisfied. Hence, there's an infinite number of such graphs.

Comment: What does a "pattern" mean to you? If a pattern is simply a short description, then "planar graphs with minimum degree at least $4$" is already a single pattern.

Comment: Alright. I'll say a "pattern" is a non-trivial short description.

Comment: It's best if questions are self-contained, and don't require users to click back to other pages.

Comment: Is there any part that I should add to make it self-contained, @GerryMyerson thank you.

Comment: It's necessary to know what's in the answer to which you link, in order to know whether we have found all the patterns.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how to answer your questions, but there are still many different ways to construct planar graphs each vertex of which has degree $\geq4$.

For example, if some planar graph each vertex of degree $\geq4$ has face size $4$ or more, then we can add three or four vertices and some edges so that we get a new planar graph where all vertices have degree $\geq4$. In the figure we add new vertices of blue color to the black face.

[image]

Moreover, the new graph has face of size $4$ or more again and we can continue the process of adding vertices.

**Addition.**
However, it is possible to add three vertices to the triangle face as well, as it is done in the figure below.

[image]